# Android GooglePlay

Tags: java, android

well, I have a question that no one was able to answer. I am an Italian developer, my app GooglePlay in Italy is in 10th place in the Finance category. How can I find a place that is in England, Germany, etc. ..? thanks

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question. It shows effort, and it is related to `software tools commonly used by programmers`. It is also a `practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`.

Comment: Try to make question title more informative

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to try [App Annie's website](http://www.appannie.com/). It seems like you'd be able to search the finance category on Google Play in multiple countries, ordered by rank.